# Pandas group operation on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a grouped pandas groupby object.

```
dis type id  date         qty
1   1    10  2017-01-01   1
1   1    10  2017-01-01   0
1   1    10  2017-01-02   4.5
1   2    11  2017-04-03   1
1   2    11  2017-04-03   2
1   2    11  2017-04-03   0
1   2    11  2017-04-05   0
```

I want to apply some operations on this groupby object.

1. I want to add a new column total_order that calculates the number of orders on a particular date for a particular material
2. A column zero_qty that calculates the number of zero orders for a particular date for a particular material
3. change the date column to make it calculate the number of days between each subsequent order for a particular material. The first order becomes 0.

The final dataframe should like something like this:

```
dis type id date  qty  total_order  zero_qty
1   1    10  0    1    2            1
1   1    10  0    0    2            1
1   1    10  1    4.5  1            1
1   2    11  0    1    3            2
1   2    11  0    2    3            2 
1   2    11  0    0    3            2
1   2    11  2    0    1            1
```

Comment: show us your what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I have only grouped the dataframe with respect to dis, type, and id and I'm stuck with the groupbyobject.
I'm unable to convert the groupby object to a dataframe without applying any of the aggregation functions. Earlier, i was summing the quantity field for a particular date to get the number of days elapsed. But I'm unable to figure out how to do it keeping my fields intact and just adding columns to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for count size of groups to `total_order`, then count number of zeros in `qty` and last get difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

Notice - for difference need sorted columns, [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) do it if necessary:

```
df = df.sort_values(['dis','type','id','date'])

g = df.groupby(['dis','type','id','date'])
df['total_order'] = g['id'].transform('size')
df['zero_qty'] = g['qty'].transform(lambda x: (x == 0).sum()).astype(int)
df['date'] =  df.groupby(['dis','type','id'])['date'].diff().fillna(0).dt.days
print (df)
   dis  type  id  date  qty  total_order  zero_qty
0    1     1  10     0  1.0            2         1
1    1     1  10     0  0.0            2         1
2    1     1  10     1  4.5            1         0
3    1     2  11     0  1.0            3         1
4    1     2  11     0  2.0            3         1
5    1     2  11     0  0.0            3         1
6    1     2  11     2  0.0            1         1
```

Another solution instead multiple `transform` use `apply` with custom function:

```
df = df.sort_values(['dis','type','id','date'])

def f(x):
    x['total_order'] = len(x)
    x['zero_qty'] =    x['qty'].eq(0).sum().astype(int)
    return x

df = df.groupby(['dis','type','id','date']).apply(f)

df['date'] =  df.groupby(['dis','type','id'])['date'].diff().fillna(0).dt.days
print (df)
   dis  type  id  date  qty  total_order  zero_qty
0    1     1  10     0  1.0            2         1
1    1     1  10     0  0.0            2         1
2    1     1  10     1  4.5            1         0
3    1     2  11     0  1.0            3         1
4    1     2  11     0  2.0            3         1
5    1     2  11     0  0.0            3         1
6    1     2  11     2  0.0            1         1
```

EDIT:

Last row can be rewrite too if need process more columns:

```
def f2(x):
    #add another code 
    x['date'] = x['date'].diff().fillna(0).dt.days
    return x

df = df.groupby(['dis','type','id']).apply(f2)
```

Comment: My original data that i posted is a groupby object (not a dataframe) grouped according to dis, type and then id. How do i get the desired output based on that grouping ? Thanks !

Comment: Simply change `g = df.groupby(['type','date'])` to `g = df.groupby(['dis','id','type','date'])` .

Comment: I change answer - because sorting by this solumn is necessary too and also added columns in last groupby.

Comment: I will try it out and let you know asap

Comment: Sure, I am waiting. My `zero_qty` column is different, so if dont understand your requirements, please explain more. Thanks.

Comment: I got the "Transform function invalid for data types" error.
Also, after the first groupby , i want to use that groupby object as my dataframe and add the total_order and zero_qty column to that groupby object and convert it to a dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 2 questions - what is `print (df.dtypes)` and what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: everything is int64 except qty (float64) and date (datetime64[ns]). Pandas 0.20.3

Comment: So problem is with sample data or real only?

Comment: I gave sample dataset here because the real one has quite a lot of columns. But the basic idea is the same, I have the data grouped exactly how i want it. The problem is i don't know how to proceed further with that groupby object to add the columns that i want

Comment: Thanks , will try it out. I have a doubt, I want my grouping to be till the id, and every order should be there for that id instead of all orders on one date being grouped into one group. Do i have to change anything for that ?

Comment: Not sure if understand, but in groupby is first parameter list of columns for grouping. So if use `.groupby(['dis','type','id','date'])` it group by columns `['dis','type','id','date']`, if `.groupby(['id'])` then it group by `id` column only. So try change this list by your needs. Or do you think something else?

Comment: Yes, my initial grouping is according to dis, type and id. Using that i get all the dates for a particular group of dis,type and id (if i have multiple orders on a particular date, i don't group them into one date, i keep the individual entries).  Now for a particular id, i find out how many orders were there on a particular date, and then add it to the total_order column for that id and date for all its occurences. Sorry if I'm not able to explain it properly

Comment: Hmmm, I think you have same problem like me in this answer - need groupby twice - once for `['dis','type','id','date']` and then for `['dis','type','id']`. I add to my answer rewrited second groupby - if need add some code to `f2`. (Also maybe order shoul be change, first call f and then f2 if necessary.)